# GDK is released. Where is the Emulator?

Tags: emulation, google-glass, google-gdk

Google Glass Development kit was released yesterday. But, I can't find any emulator. Where is it? Is there any emulator like an android emulator out there, where we can test these *native* google glass apps?

Comment: Have you checked http://glass-apps.org/google-glass-emulator?

Comment: @luanjot: That is a web based emulator for glass apps built using HTML, JSON, REST etc. Is this is working for this new 'Android' based glass api too?

Answer (score 6):

Glass is basically an android device. Just create your own ADV (using android v15) with a resolution of 640x320.

You could also use the released img/boot files to create a virtual machine running glass, just like you would any other android device (google for tuts on this).

Of course, touch/sensors/etc are a bit tricky to emulate/run, but they do work like they do on any android device. I ported my sensor code directly, and touches worked immediately using the glass.gesturerecogniser code posted on dev.google.

Comment: Hello thanks for the information, so you mean by creating an AVD like that I can compile and run the glass?

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you tested GDK app on emulator? I did the same and tried demo Stopwatch app, but Eclipse warned that there is not default activity set in the Manifest.

Answer (score 4):

There is still no Google Glass emulator in the GDK, you have to test your Glassware directly on the device installing the apk (with Eclipse or adb).

Answer (score 2):

There exist way to modify Android smartphone to work as Google Glass, see more information here: http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/11/google-glass-development-without-glass.html

Answer (score 0):

Note: There is no official emulator for Google Glass yet.